# How to use RapidShare API to get Account Details?

Tags: php, api, rapidshare

When I try to use the RapidShare API to get account details, I get a long string like this:

```
accountid=******* type=prem servertime=1247000294 addtime=********** validuntil=********* username=*****8 directstart=1 protectfiles=0 ...
```

How can I get values from it using PHP?

To be more specific, how can I set the value of `accountid` to a variable? For instance `$username = VALUE OF ACCOUNTID`? I tried `strpos`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a plain string like what you posted...

```
    $url = "accountid=*** type=prem servertime=1247000294 addtime=****** validuntil=**** username=8 directstart=1 protectfiles=0";

    $temp = explode(' ', $url);
    foreach($temp as $k => $v)
    {
        $temp[$k] = explode('=', $v);
        $data[$temp[$k][0]] = $temp[$k][1];
    }
    unset($temp);

    $data["accountid"] // stores the account ID, equal to "***"
    $data["type"]      // stores the type, equal to "prem"
    //etc....
```

It would be slightly different if it was actually a **query string**, which could be likely.